# how to drain records in a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

During application planned maintenance activities , there is a need to drain all the messages a in kafka topic.

In MQ , we can monitor the queue depth and start the maintenance activities once all the messages are consumed. In kafka  , do we have a similar mechanism to find out if all messages in the topic has been consumed and its safe to shutdown the producer and consumer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following command you can monitor the LAG of your consumer group, once the lag is 0 means no more messages in topic to consume

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group count_errors --describe
GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             OWNER
count_errors                   logs                           2          2908278         2908278         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.55
count_errors                   logs                           3          2907501         2907501         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.43
count_errors                   logs                           4          2907541         2907541         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.177
count_errors                   logs                           1          2907499         2907499         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.115
count_errors                   logs                           0          2907469         2907469         0               consumer-1_/10.8.0.126
```